# How to Retain text in Text box using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have A page for registering user Details and from this page I have an option for adding his Sate/Continent. After Adding Sate/Continent he can navigate to his previous page.. But At this time Already filled Data's are missing so that he can have to enter again this.. Is there any possibility to solve this using javascript??

Comment: There are some possibilities here, you can either make a SPA, or you can make use of session/cookies/localstorage, be aware that localstorage  is only available in IE since v8

Comment: Here I have get added state in dropdown of my first page all i wanted is get the previously entered text will remain in the text box..I have a Link button for navigating to state adding page and a link button in the state page for going back to the previous page..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are navigating away from page you can either use some server side code to create a session and retain values between pages. Or you can use js cookies to retain the values like

```
document.cookie="continent=asia";
```

Comment: Here I have get added state in dropdown of my first page all i wanted is get the previously entered text will remain in the text box..I have a Link button for navigating to state adding page and a link button in the state page for going back to the previous page..